# Not able to parse XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I need help parsing an XML variable into a table format as below. I am new to parsing looked up in google and was able to parse `AccountId`, `Email`, `ProductName` and `ProductType` but not able to parse nodes with in attribute like `CustName`, `CreatedDate`, `billingCode`

```
   DECLARE @xmlvalue XML = 
'<Request>
  <AccountId>16000</AccountId>
  <Email>test@gmail.com</Email>
  <Attributes>
  <Attribute><Name xmlns="http://testtarget.com/wsdl/myAPI">CustName</Name><Value xmlns="http://testtarget.com/wsdl/myAPI">TestName</Value></Attribute>
  <Attribute><Name xmlns="http://testtarget.com/wsdl/myAPI">CreatedDate</Name><Value xmlns="http://testtarget.com/wsdl/myAPI">3/26/2022</Value></Attribute>
  <Attribute><Name xmlns="http://testtarget.com/wsdl/myAPI">BillingCode</Name><Value xmlns="http://testtarget.com/wsdl/myAPI">testbiling</Value></Attribute>
  </Attributes>
  <ProductName>TestProduct</ProductName>
  <ProductType>Recurring</ProductType>
</Request>'
```

Expected OUTPUT :

```
AccountId  Email           CustName  CreatedDate  BillingCode  ProductName ProductType
1600       test@gmail.com  TestName   03/26/2022  testbiling  TestProduct  Recurring
```

Below code is giving me what I wanted. Is there an easy approach?

```
SELECT req.req_col.value('AccountId[1]','INT')       AS AccountId, 
       req.req_col.value('Email[1]','VARCHAR(100)')  AS Email,
       req.req_col.value('ProductName[1]','VARCHAR(100)')    AS ProductName,
       req.req_col.value('ProductType[1]','VARCHAR(100)')    AS ProductType,
       v.CustName,
       v.CreatedDate,
       v.BillingCode
FROM @xmlvalue.nodes('/Request')                                req(req_col)
CROSS APPLY  ( SELECT *
                FROM (SELECT req.req_col.value('Name[1]','VARCHAR(100)')     AS Name,
                           req.req_col.value('Value[1]','VARCHAR(100)')      AS Value
                      FROM @xmlvalue.nodes('/Request/Attributes/Attribute') req(req_col)
                     ) tab1
                PIVOT (
                MAX(Value) FOR Name IN ( CustName, CreatedDate, BillingCode )) Tab2
           ) v
```

Comment: Show us your code so far !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we are here to help you solve programming problems and bugs, be aware that we're not a free code writing service. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71746372/edit) your question to include the SQL code that you've tried so far and tell us why you think it's not meeting your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use `PIVOT` for this, you can use filters in XPath expressions to select the various Attribute Name-Value element pairs, e.g.:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  'http://testtarget.com/wsdl/myAPI' as anything
)
select
  request.value(N'(AccountId/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as AccountId,
  request.value(N'(Email/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as Email,
  request.value(N'(Attributes/Attribute[anything:Name/text()="CustName"]/anything:Value/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as CustName,
  request.value(N'(Attributes/Attribute[anything:Name/text()="CreatedDate"]/anything:Value/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as CreatedDate,
  request.value(N'(Attributes/Attribute[anything:Name/text()="BillingCode"]/anything:Value/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as BillingCode,
  request.value(N'(ProductName/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as ProductName,
  request.value(N'(ProductType/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as ProductType
from @xmlvalue.nodes('/Request') foo(request);
```

| AccountId | Email | CustName | CreatedDate | BillingCode | ProductName | ProductType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16000 | test@gmail.com | TestName | 3/26/2022 | testbiling | TestProduct | Recurring |

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Actual code has xml namespace in it. Can your answer be tweaked when they exist ? I went and updated xmldata just for your reference – 
pradeep kandula

Comment: Updated with namespace references. NOTE: When using `with xmlnamespaces` be sure that the previous statement is correctly terminated with a semicolon `;` character. You should end every T-SQL statement with a semicolon `;` as a matter of standard practice.

Comment: AlwaysLearning Worked like charm after incorporating to real code. Thankyou for timely input and explanation.